# Node fs.writeFileSync error

Tags: json, node.js

I'm currently doing a Node.JS course where we are working on reading, writing, saving and editing the user's input data through the terminal using fs.writeFileSync(). It works fine for text which is a few sentences long, but anything larger and instead of running the code, the node terminal (>) starts to run.
[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

I have a basic understanding of node.js, but can't figure out why this keeps happening.
Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Code below,

```
const fs = require('fs');

var originalNote = {
    title: process.argv[2],
    body: process.argv[3],
};

var originalNoteString = JSON.stringify(originalNote);

fs.writeFileSync('Notes.json', originalNoteString);

var noteString = fs.readFileSync('Notes.json');

var Note = JSON.parse(noteString);

console.log(typeof (Note));
console.log(originalNoteString);
console.log(Note.title);
```

- Terminal Output 1-

> Viveks-MacBook-Pro:playground Vivek$ node JSON.js 'Lorem Ipsum'
>   'ldfdfefnhebfhbfhrbfherbfhrbfhrefocalStorage fefef fede'
>
> object
>
> {"title":"Lorem
>   Ipsum","body":"ldfdfefnhebfhbfhrbfherbfhrbfhrefocalStorage fefef
>   fede"}

- Terminal Output2-

> Viveks-MacBook-Pro:playground Vivek$ node JSON.js 'Lorem Ipsum' 'Lorem
>   Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
>   Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
>   1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it
>   to make a typespecimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
>   but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
>   unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
>   Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
>   with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
>   versions of Lorem Ipsum'

'>'

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to share your code or the idea you are working on. It will help people understand the problem in better way! :)

Comment: Hi!, Yea sure I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is in the data sent in second argument.

If you look at the data, it has the word `industry's` which involves `single quote` in it.

this is causing the second argument to get truncated.

If you put the second argument in a double quote, your code should work fine.

You can also use escape characters if possible to ignore the single quotes in the data.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Call "notes.json" directly using require rather than reading it as a file.

```
var noteString = require('Notes.json');
```

If your json is properly formed, you can directly work with it. If you insist on calling the file via readFileSync, use 'utf-8' as an additional parameter.

```
var noteString = fs.readFileSync('Notes.json','utf-8');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its not recommended to `require` a `JSON` file.

Comment: The problem is with writing the large text data to the file rather than reading it. I am able to read it without any issues. My mac terminal starts the node terminal (>) when I pass the large text.

Comment: As @vibhor1997a pointed it out, requiring `JSON` caches the loaded module. So requiring a `JSON` file may become a pain if you are expecting the JSON file to change over the time. reference - https://goenning.net/2016/04/14/stop-reading-json-files-with-require/